# why is this print statement giving me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

all of the print statements in the while loop are giving me errors
i have no idea why it looks ok on paper so if you have anything let me know im thinking maybe its a problem with the values and the print statement both in one while loop

```
w = False
a = False
v = False



if action == "w":
    w = True
if action == "v":
    v = True
if action == "a":
    a = True

while w == True:

    volts = input("Volts: ")
    amperes = input("Amps: ")
    volts = int(volts)
    amperes = int(amperes)
    print("Your Watts Are " + volts * amperes)
    w = False

while v == True:

    watts = input("Watts: ")
    amperes = input("Amps: ")
    watts = int(watts)
    amperes = int(amperes)
    print("Your Volts Are " + watts // amperes)
    v == False

while a == True:

    watts = input("Watts: ")
    volts = input("Volts: ")
    watts = int(watts)
    amperes = int(amperes)
    print("Your Amps Are " + watts // volts)
    a = False





end = input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: If you want to concatenate an int/float with a string, you need to convert it first, e.g. `print("Your Amps Are " + str(watts // volts))`

Comment: what is `action` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to concatenate a `string` with an `int` or `float`, python will raise a `TypeError`. You first need to convert the numeric value to a `string`, for example:

```
print("Your Amps Are " + str(watts // volts))
```

Alternatively, you may use string formatting:

```
print("Your Amps Are {}".format(watts // volts))
```

or, in python > 3.6:

```
print(f"Your Amps Are {watts // volts}")
```